# Bordered rounded rectangle in glsl

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

Hello I am trying to get a fast rounded rectangle glsl shader but I've only managed to do it for a filled rectangle using this function (https://github.com/marklundin/glsl-sdf-primitives/blob/master/udRoundBox.glsl):

```
float udRoundBox( vec3 p, vec3 b, float r )
{
  return length(max(abs(p)-b,0.0))-r;
}
```

I've been trying to find a version of this that does a border rather than a fill, even tried to come up with one, but no luck. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using signed distance functions, the simplest way to do it is probably to use a substraction operator to substract a smaller rounded box from the initial one.

It would look like this :

```
// unsigned round box
float udRoundBox( vec3 p, vec3 b, float r )
{
  return length(max(abs(p)-b,0.0))-r;
}

// substracts shape d1 from shape d2
float opS( float d1, float d2 )
{
    return max(-d1,d2);
}

// to get the border of a udRoundBox, simply substract a smaller udRoundBox !
float udRoundBoxBorder( vec3 p, vec3 b, float r, float borderFactor )
{
  return opS(udRoundBox(p, b*borderFactor, r), udRoundBox(p, b, r));
}
```

`borderFactor` needs to be a value in `[0:1]`, the bigger it is, the small the border will be.

Here is a [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdlfRH) sample demonstrating this :
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think here's what you are searching for...

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
// draw rectangle frame with rounded edges
//---------------------------------------------------------
float roundedFrame (vec2 pos, vec2 size, float radius, float thickness)
{
  float d = length(max(abs(uv - pos),size) - size) - radius;
  return smoothstep(0.55, 0.45, abs(d / thickness) * 5.0);
}
```

Take a look at my shadertoy examples https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MssyRN
[image: screen shot example].

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a secondary box to extrude the first one is a bad idea, as it will lead to worse performance. Instead of computing a single object, you compute two objects. SDFs performance are usually bound by the number of objects you add in your distance function; this is the reason why mod/floor functions are so useful when making SDFs. You can add an infinite number of object for (almost) no added cost.

Use the box signed exact function here http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm If you want to write it yourself, try to figure out a way of getting the closest point on the box, then return the distance to this point.

You can get a rounded box by subtracting a term to the distance, but you already figured it out (r in your exemple).

You can get a border by using the absolute value of the distance. Abs(de) will basically remove the inside of the object (negative distance) by making it positive. This make an object with an "empty" border. If you want to make the border bigger, simply subtract another term to increase its size, just like you did to make a rounded box.

This works for any shape, as long as the distance estimation is correct. SDFs are great for little tricks like that.