# How to create a proper rounded rectangle in WebGL?

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I have tried to implement the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970170/bordered-rounded-rectangle-in-glsl) but there seems to be a bit of a problem. If you open their ShaderToys and try changing the border radius, the size (width and height) of the rounded rectangle change as well.

I'm looking for a solution like [this shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WtdSDs) where changing the border radius doesn't change the size of the shape. Unfortunately in this shader toy, it's a filled in rounded rectangle.

Is it possible to have a non-filled in rounded rectangle (so, only the border), but *also* have it such that if you change the border radius that the shape doesn't grow or shrink size?

I'm looking to implement a similar effect to CSS where you can specify the `border-radius` of a `div` and it only changes the border's radius without also changing the size of the shape.

Here's an image demonstrating the problem. The left result was with `boxRounding` set to `0.5` and the right result was with `boxRounding` set to `0.20`. Notice how they're a much different size. Is there any way to make both shapes the same size, but just with a different border radius?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a rectangular outline you have to compute the absolut value of the fragment to the outline:

```c
float smoothedAlpha = 
    1.0 - smoothstep(-edgeSoftness, edgeSoftness, abs(distance) - thickness);
```

Complete shadertoy shader ([2D rounded rectangular outline](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/7tsXRN) ):

[image]

```c
// from http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm
float roundedBoxSDF(vec2 CenterPosition, vec2 Size, float Radius)
{
    return length(max(abs(CenterPosition)-Size+Radius,0.0))-Radius;
}

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord)
{
    vec2  size           = vec2(300.0, 200.0);
    vec2  location       = iMouse.xy;
    float thickness      = 5.0;
    float shadowSoftness = 30.0f;
    vec2  shadowOffset   = vec2(10.0, -10.0);
    float edgeSoftness   = 1.0;
    float radius         = (sin(iTime*2.0) + 1.0) * 30.0 + thickness * 2.0;
    
    float distance       = roundedBoxSDF(location - fragCoord.xy, size/2.0, radius);
    float smoothedAlpha  = 1.0 - smoothstep(-edgeSoftness, edgeSoftness, abs(distance) - thickness);
    vec4  quadColor      = mix(vec4(1.0), vec4(0.0, 0.2, 1.0, smoothedAlpha), smoothedAlpha);
    
    float shadowDistance = roundedBoxSDF(location + shadowOffset - fragCoord.xy, size/2.0, radius);
    float shadowAlpha    = 1.0 - smoothstep(-shadowSoftness/2.0, shadowSoftness/2.0, abs(shadowDistance));
    vec4 shadowColor     = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0);
    fragColor            = mix(quadColor, shadowColor, shadowAlpha - smoothedAlpha);
}
```